# SQL Conversion Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a temp table where i am creating all the values of column to a comma separated list.. the issue i am facing is when i am inputting that csv variable i am getting error 
For ex

```
Declare @testvar varchar (max)
Select  @testvar = stuff (( select (','''+ cast(var1 as varchar(1024)+'''')
From # Temp for xmlpath('')),1,2,'') from #Temp

Select * from tab1 where col1 in (@testvar)
```

This is appending single quotes in query i am getting error like 
Conversion failed while converting varchar value ''1','2'........ to int

Any suggestions for this

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `# Temp` would be a wrong syntax

Comment: You will need to provide more information. At the very least. please provide the exact error message (you write "error like". Please copy/paste the full message. Also show us what #temp looks like. Column names, and data types.

Comment: That was a typo its actually  #Temp i am using sql server 2014

Comment: Thats the exact error the conversion failure  col1 is INT

Comment: What i am doing is creating comma separated values of integers to pass it to my table

Comment: Why aren't you just doing `Select * from tab1 where col1 in (select var1 from #Temp)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to like doing dynamic SQL. make sure your brackets are all corresponded and correctly.

```
set @testvar= stuff( 
(select ',''' + cast(var1 as varchar(1024))+ ''''
From #Temp for xml path(''))
,1,1,'') 


Select * from tab1 where col1 in (@testvar)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=261fed2f7a6cff6a3b3aea1055637f36)

Here is a sample

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(
    var1 INT
);

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (2);

create table tab1(
  col1 int
);

insert into tab1 values (1)
insert into tab1 values (3)

Declare @testvar varchar (max)
Declare @query varchar (max)

set @testvar= stuff( 
(select ',''' + cast(var1 as varchar(1024))+ ''''
From #Temp for xml path(''))
,1,1,'') 


SET @query = 'Select * from tab1 where col1 in ('+@testvar+')'



execute(@QUERY)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `IN` operator expects a list of values. You are supplying it with a single value that happens to contain a comma delimited text. There's a difference that seems very subtle as a human, but to SQL Server it's a huge difference.

A query like

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE Col1 IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

will return all rows where col1 has the value `A`, `B` or `C`, while a query like

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE Col1 IN ('''A'', ''B'', ''C''')
```

will return only the records where col1 has the value `'A', 'B', 'C'` - so basically it's like writing

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE Col1 = '''A'', ''B'', ''C'''
```

What you should do is using the temporary table directly:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tab1 
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM #Temp as tmp
    WHERE tmp.Var1 = Tab1.Col1
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot 

Comment: Glad to help :-)